# Flex Slider Issue Fade effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I'm using flex slider in my html .
I have followed given steps to add slider in my html page.
Slider works well When animation = "slide" But 
Not working properly when animation = "fade" ;
Fade effect does not show proper slides .

here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({ 
    animation: "fade",
    animationSpeed: 1000,
    direction: "horizontal",
    slideshowSpeed: 2000,
    pauseOnHover: true, 
    slideshow: true,
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }           
  });
});
</script>
```

Help me out.
thank's

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something with the CSS.  I would create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can see your code and also explain exactly what you mean by "Fade effect does not show proper slides". What happens? Anything?

If you do that then I'm sure you'll get it figured out on here...

Comment: The view of slider in "fade" ,showing half of the images and images blur.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Animation: "slide" worked fine but when I tried to use "fade" I wasn't able to click the thumbnails to change the slides. There is nothing wrong with the flex slider or the javascript. It works great in the flex slider demo, so...

**Try fiddling with the positioning/layering** of the `<ol>`. The thumbnails are probably layered beneath the main slide image, making it impossible to actually click them.

This worked for me:

```
ol.flex-control-thumbs {clear: both;}
```

But you can also try playing with **positioning** and **z-index** if clearing doesn't work. It's going to depend heavily on how your HTML and CSS is structured. If that `<ol>` thumbnail list can wiggle it's way underneath the slider, it will. And nobody likes not being able to click stuff!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, solution was simple.

Thumbnails work well, but its "under" the slides. Just set `.flex-control-nav` with high `z-index`.

```
.flex-control-nav{
    z-index:500;
}
```

Should work.